# Reverse subsetting a vector in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to reverse subset code in R.  Here is an example of my code below. Instead of returning the 20 characters beyond the comma, i want to return the 20 characters prior to the comma.  Thanks in advance.

```
substr(test,gregexpr(pattern =',',test),20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Sample "text"
text = "asdasdasdasd,asdasdasdasdasd"
index = gregexpr(pattern =',',text)[[1]]
substr(text,(index-20), index)

> substr(text,(index-20), index)
[1] "asdasdasdasd,"
```

`substr` will return up till the beginning if there are less than 20 characters from ",".

```
> substr(text,(index-5), index)
[1] "sdasd,"
```